# Access HttpContextAccessor from startup.cs in .net Core WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm logging exceptions to database in asp.net core. MyDbContext take HttpContextAccessor parameter.So, I'm sending HttpContextAccessor to MyDbContext.cs for access my JWT. But, I can't access my HttpContextAccessor from Startup.cs. How can I achieve this?

Startup.cs

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
         app.UseExceptionHandler(builder => builder.Run(async context =>
         {
             var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

             context.Response.AddApplicationError(error,???????);//I want access HttpContextAccessor
             await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
         }));

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

ExceptionHelper.cs

```
 public static class ExceptionHelper
    {
        public static async Task AddApplicationError(this HttpResponse response, IExceptionHandlerFeature error, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
           Log log = new Log();
           log.Message = error.Error.Message;          

           MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext(null, httpContextAccessor);
           UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(context);
           uow.LogRepo.AddOrUpdate(log);
           await uow.CompleteAsync(false);               
        }
    }
```

MyDbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(GetOptions())
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    private static DbContextOptions GetOptions()
    {
        return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), "server=asd; database=; user id=asd; password=1234").Options;
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var token = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        var audits = AuditHelper.AddAuditLog(base.ChangeTracker, token);
        return (await base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can inject whatever you need into the `Configure` method. You have already added it to the service collection with this line:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

So all you need to do is add it to the list of arguments on the method like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
{
    // make use of it here
}
```

As an aside: I would also point out that it's a bit of a code smell that you are manually creating an instance of your `DbContext` inside your static helper class when you are using dependency injection.

**Update in response to comment**

In order to tidy things up a bit I would start by changing your startup to configure you DbContext something like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // register other things here...

        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(
            config.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString") // from appsettings.json
        ));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // set up app here...
    }
}
```

You can then remove the `.GetOptions()` method from `MyDbContext`, and change the constructor to:

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    : base(options)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Then you inject an instance of `MyDbContext` into whatever class needs access to it. The problem is that (to my knowledge) DI does not work well with static classes/methods, and you are using an extension method on the `HttpResponse` to log your error.

In my opinion it would be better to create a class that is responsible for logging the error with a dependency on your `MyDbContext` and have that injected into the `Configure` method:

```
public class ErrorLogger
{
    private MyDataContext db;

    public ErrorLogger(MyDataContext db) => this.db = db;

    public void LogError(IExceptionHandlerFeature error)
    {
        Log log = new Log();
        log.Message = error.Error.Message; 

        UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(this.db);
        uow.LogRepo.AddOrUpdate(log);
        await uow.CompleteAsync(false);
    }
}
```

Register it with the DI container as you have with other things, then inject it into `Configure` instead of the HTTP accessor:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ErrorLogger logger)
{
     app.UseExceptionHandler(builder => builder.Run(async context =>
     {
         var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
         logger.LogError(error);
         await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
     }));
}
```

I have not tested this, and I am not familiar with `.UseExceptionHandler(...)` as I use application insights to log exceptions etc (take a look at it if you've not seen it). One thing to be aware of is the scope of your dependencies; your DbContext will be `Scoped` by default (and I think you should leave it that way), which means you cannot inject it into `Singleton` objects.

Comment: Thanks it worked @Ben. Yes, I think I'm doing something wrong. How can I achieve access from MyDbContext without always sending parameter as HttpContextAccessor? Because I need JWT information in MyDbContext. Can you fix my code?

Comment: All done, take it with a pinch of salt though! Take a look at the answers to some of the questions I have asked on here for insight from experts.

Comment: @realist if you configure services/di-container correctly, you don't  need to create manually DbContext instances , the framework will inject dependencies in the constructor for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad design inject httpContext into DbContext.

If you need to log errors to database, the error log need to be an entity:

```cs
  public class LogEntry
  {
    prop int Id {get; set;}
    prop string Message { get; set; }

    //etc whatever properties you want to persist
  }
```

Then you just inject your DbContext into your controller by placing it into the constructor:

```cs
public class MyController: Controller
{
  private readonly MyDbContext _context;

  public MyController(MyDbContext context) {
    this._context = context;
  }
}
```

Then you should create an exception handler to catch you errors.

The preferred method for handling global errors in ASP.NET core is the Global Exception Middleware.

```cs
public class ExceptionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;
 
        public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, MyDbContext context)
        {
            _next = next;
            _context = context;
        }
 
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(httpContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await LogToDabase(ex);
                await HandleGlobalExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
            }
        }

        private async Task LogToDatabase(Exception ex)
        {
            var logEntry = new LogEntry()
            {
               Message = ex.ToString()
            }
            _context.Add(logEntry);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
 
        private static Task HandleGlobalExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(new GlobalErrorDetails()
            {
                StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
                Message = "Something went wrong !Internal Server Error"
            }.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Register the filter:

```cs
public static class GlobalExceptionMiddleware
    {
        public static void UseGlobalExceptionMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```