# ASP.NET Core HttpContext is null outside controller in case of Batch request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata, httpcontext

In my ASP.NET Core OData service, when we make a batch request and try to access `HttpContext` outside the controller, it is null. In the case of not batch request `HttpContext` is populated correctly.

I am using `IHttpContextAccessor` to get the `httpContext`:

```
public static class AspnetcoreHttpContext
{
    public static IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

    public static void SetContextAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        contextAccessor = accessor;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current HTTP Context. This may be null!!!
    /// </summary>
    public static HttpContext Current
    {
            get
            {
                return contextAccessor?.HttpContext;
            }
    }
}
```

In starup I have configured batch as below;

```
app.UseODataBatching();
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
            {
                var conventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
                ODataBatchHandler odataBatchHandler = new CustomODataBatchHandler();
                ApiVersion version = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                string routeName = string.Format("odata-bypath{0}", version.MajorVersion.Value);
                routeBuilder.MapVersionedODataRoute(routeName, "odata/v{version:apiVersion}",
                    EdmModel, version, new DefaultODataPathHandler(), conventions, batchHandler: odataBatchHandler);
            });
```

Any pointers? please suggest.

Comment: you will always find `HttpContext` null, whenever you are trying to access it from batch request.`HttpContext.Current` is a context that has been created during the active request.

Comment: You need to be resolved in the startup file and register in specific outside of controller class you can get the values.

Comment: You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927463/access-httpcontextaccessor-from-startup-cs-in-net-core-webapi)

Comment: Thanks @Vishalmodi, is there any workaround to do it.

Comment: Thanks @Jishan, I have followed the same steps mentioned in the link. I am not able to get the HttpContext in case of batch request. Do you mean to say, it should also work in batch request.